# Filter parameters from query String (using Guava?)

Tags: java, guava

Take this HTTP query String:

```
foo=fooValue&bar=barValue&phleem=phleemValue
```

Or this one:

```
bar=barValue&phleem=phleemValue&foo=someOtherFoo
```

What would be the best way to remove the `foo` parameter?

All Java solutions welcome, but Guava preferred.

(There is no ServletContext available, so Servlet methods won't help)

**Update:** The method should handle multiple parameters to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution, but works as you expect:

```
private String removeParameter(String string, final String parameterName) {
    List<String> list = newArrayList(string.split("&"));

    Collection<String> filtered = Collections2.filter(list, new Predicate<String>() {
        public boolean apply(String s) {
            return !s.startsWith(parameterName + "=");
        }
    });

    return Joiner.on("&").join(filtered);
}
```

**UPDATE**

To handle multiple parameters:

```
@Test
public void removesMultipleParametersFromQuery() throws Exception {
    String result = removeParameters("foo=fooValue&zee=lalal&bar=barValue&phleem=phleemValue", "foo", "bar");
    assertThat(result, is("zee=lalal&phleem=phleemValue"));
}

private String removeParameters(String query, final String...parameterNames) {
    List<String> list = newArrayList(query.split("&"));
    return Joiner.on("&").join(filter(list, startsWithAnyOf(parameterNames)));
}

private Predicate<String> startsWithAnyOf(final String[] parameterNames) {
    return new Predicate<String>() {
        public boolean apply(String s) {
            return !Iterables.any(newArrayList(parameterNames), isPrefixOf(s));
        }
    };
}

private Predicate<String> isPrefixOf(final String string){
    return new Predicate<String>() {
        public boolean apply(String candidate) {
            return string.startsWith(candidate);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own solution (but it's ugly as hell):

```
public static String removeParameters(final String queryString,
    final String... paramNames){
    Iterable<Predicate<CharSequence>> innerPredicates;
    if(paramNames.length == 0){
        innerPredicates = Collections.emptySet();
    } else{
        innerPredicates =
            Iterables.transform(
            Arrays.asList(paramNames),
                new Function<String, Predicate<CharSequence>>(){

                    @Override
                    public Predicate<CharSequence> apply(
                        final String input){

                        return Predicates.contains(
                            Pattern.compile("^"
                            + Pattern.quote(input) + "=")
                        );
                    }
                });
    }

    final Predicate<CharSequence> predicate =
        Predicates.not(Predicates.or(innerPredicates));
    return Joiner.on("&").join(
        Iterables.filter(Splitter.on('&').split(queryString), predicate));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have something to read the query string in as a `Multimap<String, String>` on one end and something to write a `Multimap<String, String>` in query string format on the other. Then doing this is as simple as calling `removeAll(parameter)` for each parameter you want to remove from the query string. Don't deal with something like that as a raw `String` except at the points where you absolutely have to.

Here's some code for that:

```
private static final Splitter QUERY_SPLITTER = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("&;"));
private static final Joiner QUERY_JOINER = Joiner.on('&');
private static final EntrySplitFunction ENTRY_SPLITTER = 
    new EntrySplitFunction(Splitter.on('='));
private static final EntryJoinFunction ENTRY_JOINER = 
    new EntryJoinFunction(Joiner.on('=').useForNull(""));

public static Multimap<String, String> parseQueryString(String queryString) {
  Multimap<String, String> result = HashMultimap.create();
  Iterable<String> entryStrings = QUERY_SPLITTER.split(queryString);
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : transform(entryStrings, ENTRY_SPLITTER)) {
    result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  }
  return result;
}

public static String toQueryString(Multimap<String, String> multimap) {
  return QUERY_JOINER.join(transform(multimap.entries(), ENTRY_JOINER));
}

private static class EntrySplitFunction 
    implements Function<String, Map.Entry<String, String>> {
  private final Splitter keyValueSplitter;

  private EntrySplitFunction(Splitter keyValueSplitter) {
    this.keyValueSplitter = keyValueSplitter;
  }

  @Override public Map.Entry<String, String> apply(String input) {
    Iterator<String> keyAndValue = keyValueSplitter.split(input).iterator();
    return Maps.immutableEntry(keyAndValue.next(), keyAndValue.next());
  }
}

private static class EntryJoinFunction 
    implements Function<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> {
  private final Joiner keyValueJoiner;

  private EntryJoinFunction(Joiner keyValueJoiner) {
    this.keyValueJoiner = keyValueJoiner;
  }

  @Override public String apply(Map.Entry<String, String> input) {
    return keyValueJoiner.join(input.getKey(), input.getValue());
  }
}
```

With this, all you'd have to do to implement your method is:

```
public static String removeParameters(String queryString, String... parameters) {
  Multimap<String, String> query = parseQueryString(queryString);
  for (String parameter : parameters) {
    query.removeAll(parameter);
  }
  return toQueryString(query);
}
```

Better yet, assuming there's anything else you do with the query, you'd just have the `Multimap` already when you reach the point that you need to do this and you wouldn't even bother writing a special method for it.

Comment: about the last sentence: the use case is that the query String has to be sent to an external service that apparently needs a few reserved parameters removed. I don't know why, the question was for a colleague.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava

```
public static String toQueryString(final Map<String, Object> queryParameters) {
        return "?" + Joiner.on('&').withKeyValueSeparator("=").join(queryParameters);
    }
```

Comment: The problem is: this fails both with duplicate params `foo=bar1&foo=bar2`and with empty params `foo&bar`or `foo=&bar=`, all of which are legal constructs

Comment: Instead, I would currently probably use Spring's [`UriComponentsBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html?is-external=true)

Comment: Duplicates would actually work if you use a `Multimap<String, Object>` and  pass `entries()` to the `join` method: `Joiner.on("&").withKeyValueSeperator("=").join(params.entries());`